# How do I show a hidden DIV with Jquery when a user clicks a radio box?

Tags: jquery, radio-button, show

I am having difficulty showing a hidden div when a user selects a radio box.

This is my code:

The Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".paypalmethod").click(function() {
  $(".paypalinfo").show('slow');

});

</script>
```

The html

```
<input name="method" type="radio" value="paypal" class="paypalmethod"/><img src="/images/paymentlogos/PayPal.png" />

<div class="paypalinfo" style="display:none">Paypal the safe and easy way to pay. Paypal accepts all major credit cards.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing `});` in your code, you need to close the `document.ready` and the `.click()`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //or just $(function() { works here as well
  $(".paypalmethod").click(function() {
    $(".paypalinfo:hidden").show('slow');
  });
});
```

Also, to not produce a fade when the element's already visible, add a [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) in like I have above.  This makes it only find/fade in the element if it's currently hidden, and wont re-fade it in when it's already shown.

Answer (score 0):

It's a syntax error. You need to close your second function and jQuery call:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".paypalmethod").click(function() {
    $(".paypalinfo").show('slow');
  });
});

</script>
```